# Number Compare c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I am supposed to write a program that asks the user three integers and then assigns those three ints from largest to smallest. If you could give me tips and help me with this.

```
#include <iostream> // allows program to perform input and output

using std::cout; // program uses cout
using std::endl; // program uses endl
using std::cin; // program uses cin

int main()
{
    int number1; // first integer read from user
    int number2; // second integer read from user
    int number3; // third integer read from user
    int smallest; // smallest integer read from user
    int largest; // largest integer read from user


    cout << "Input three different integers: "; // prompt
    cin >> number1 >> number2 >> number3;

    largest = number1; // assume first integer is largest

    if (number2 > number1){
    number2 = largest;
    }

    if (number3 > number2) {
    number3 = largest;
    }

    smallest = number1; // assume first integer is smallest

    if (number2 < number1) {
    number2 = smallest;
    }


    if (number3 < number2) {
    number3 = smallest;
    }

    cout << "Max" << largest;
    cout << "Min" << smallest;

    /* Write an output statement that prints the sum, average,
    product, largest and smallest */

    return 0; // indicate successful termination    
} // end main
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  Can you tell us what exactly isn't working? What are your inputs?

Comment: If `number2 > number1` then `largest` must get a new value. It is currently assigning `largest` to `number2`. Same with `number3` etc.

Comment: @user3853544, You can't tell? He's obviously using the assignment operator wrong.

Comment: @Blindy Well I was going to wait for him to respond then suggest he step through with a debugger.  Just because the error is obvious to us does not mean its obvious for him.

Comment: @user3853544, I didn't say it was obvious to him, I said that it should be obvious to you. Asking for more information (in this case) is useless, it's just noise people who don't know much spam with to make themselves feel relevant to a conversation.

Comment: Hello @user7480528, I've provided an answer below. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that this is a typo or an attempt at doing something crafty that went awry, but

```
number2 = largest;
```

and its friends seem to be assigning in the wrong direction. The reason that I think it could be a logic mistake is

```
largest = number1; // assume first integer is largest

if (number2 > largest){ // formerly number2 > number1 and largest == number1 
    largest = number2;
}

if (number3 > largest) { // formerly number3 > number2 and continuing from above 
                         // number2 may have been equal to largest. This is where 
                         // the logic breaks down
    largest = number3;
}
```

would be a reasonable way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Besides to some logic errors, the problem lies in how you have used the equal sign, referred to in c++ as the copy assignment operator. I'll explain how it works:

#### In simple terms, the assignment operator (=) serves the purpose of copying the value on the right-hand side of the equal sign to the variable on the left side of the equal sign.

Simply, if we do this:

```
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    b = a;
```

This copies the value stored on the right side of the assignment operator (i.e from `a`) to the variable on the left side (i.e to `b`). In effect, the variable `b` stores the value 2 now, not 3. On the other hand, `a` retains the value 2.

However, if we did this:

```
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    a = b;
```

This would mean that `a` now stores the same value as `b` stores, which is 3, while `b` still stores 3.

The problem in your code is not the logic, but rather the improper use of the assignment operator, because in the following lines:

```
    number2 = largest;
    number3 = largest;
```

Instead of setting the variable `largest` to `number2` or `number3`, depending on the input, you are unknowingly setting the value of `number2` or `number3` to the current largest value, which would be the value of number1. This is because in the line:

```
    largest = number1; // assume first integer is largest
```

You set the variable largest to the value in number1. That's why you would notice that your max value is always the value in `number1`.

This same problem persists when you try to find the smallest value, because your smallest value is set to `number1` again, just like above, and you set this value to `number2` or `number3` instead of moving the smallest value **from** `number2` or `number3`.

---

Another problem is your logic. Consider the following lines (I've fixed your equal signs):

```
largest = number1; // assume first integer is largest

if (number2 > number1){
largest = number2;
}

if (number3 > number2) {
largest = number3;
}
```

Now let's use the number 3, 1, 2 for `number1`, `number2`, `number3` respectively. We begin by setting `number1` to 3. We then compare number1 to number2, which gives us 1 > 3, and this is false, so the largest number remains number1. However, you then make the comparison to see if `number3 > number2`, and this means 2 > 1, which is true. So as a result, you allocate `largest` to number3, even though you make no comparison between `number3` and `number1`. The same problem persists in your logic for finding the smallest value.

Here's some logic that works (I've tried and tested it):

```
if (number1 > number2)
{
    if (number1 > number3)
        largest = number1;
    else
        largest = number3;
}
else
{
    if (number2 > number3)
        largest = number2;
    else
        largest = number3;
}

if (number1 < number2)
{
    if (number1 < number3)
        smallest = number1;
    else
        smallest = number3;
}
else
{
    if (number2 < number3)
        smallest = number2;
    else
        smallest = number3;
}
```

Hope this answers your question.